# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904

Tags: 2010

I am having the following scenario.
All day something I am testing has  been working fine. but suddently I start receiving this error when I try to do the following line:

```
 query.RowLimit = 1;
                    SPListItemCollection itemsMeetings = listMeetingsRoot.GetItems(query);

                    if (itemsMeetings.Count == 1)
                    {
```

I am not going to show the full code because I think the error is related to sql server. but I dont know what to check
1. I checked tempdb it has 7mb of space.
2. I checked content database it has 60mb of data.

some errors I can see in the logs are:

```
Unable to execute query: Error 0x80131904
SqlError: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 102 State: 1 Class: 15 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 1 Server:

...spaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.Sql...
```

there are too many sql errors in the log, so I dont know what can I check

string startDateStr = startDate.ToString("s");
                #endregion

```
            #region Get Next meeting                  

            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = string.Concat(
                "<Where>",
                "<And>",
                       "<BeginsWith>",
                    "<FieldRef Name='" + Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_TEXT_TITLE_NAME + "' />",
                    "<Value Type='Text'>" + type + "</Value>",
                "</BeginsWith>",
                "<Ge>",
                    "<FieldRef Name='" + Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_EVENTDATE_NAME + "' />",
                    "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>" + startDateStr + "</Value>",
                "</Ge>",
                "</And>",
                "</Where>");
            query.RowLimit = 1;
            SPListItemCollection itemsMeetings = listMeetingsRoot.GetItems(query);
            #endregion

            #region Get url of next meeting site
            if (itemsMeetings.Count == 1)
```

this is the generated query

```
<Where><And><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>BD</Value></BeginsWith><Ge><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>2012-08-15T00:00:00</Value></Ge></And></Where>
```

Comment: The SQL query is malformed. What's your CAML look like?

Comment: please see the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things here.

First, the CAML schema uses `<Geq>` rather than `<Ge>`. See [Query Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx).

Second, SharePoint dates comply to ISO 8601 standards. This requires you to include Zulu in the string (as in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`). See [SharePoint 2010: Working With Dates in CAML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/414414/SharePoint-2010-Working-with-Dates-in-CAML).

Comment: shame on me, I meant gt..

Comment: Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: What would be the chances. Exactly same issue with the Ge vs Geq. My COBOL days of old have come back to haunt me.